# GLPK output formats

Tags: linear-programming, glpk

I am new to GLPK, so my apologies in advance if I'm missing something simple!

I have a largeish LP that I am feeding through GLPK to model an energy market. I'm running the following command line to GLPK to process this:

```
winglpk-4.65\glpk-4.65\w64\glpsol --lp problem.lp --data ExampleDataFile.dat --output results2.txt
```

When I open the resulting text file I can see the outputs, which all look sensible. I have one big problem: each record is split over two rows, making it very difficult to clean the file. See an extract below:

```
   No.   Row name   St   Activity     Lower bound   Upper bound    Marginal
------ ------------ -- ------------- ------------- ------------- -------------
     1 c_e_SpecifiedDemand(UTOPIA_CSV_ID_1990)_
                    NS             0             0             =         < eps
     2 c_e_SpecifiedDemand(UTOPIA_CSV_ID_1991)_
                    NS             0             0             =         < eps
     3 c_e_SpecifiedDemand(UTOPIA_CSV_ID_1992)_
                    NS             0             0             =         < eps
     4 c_e_SpecifiedDemand(UTOPIA_CSV_ID_1993)_
                    NS             0             0             =         < eps
     5 c_e_SpecifiedDemand(UTOPIA_CSV_ID_1994)_
                    NS             0             0             =         < eps
     6 c_e_SpecifiedDemand(UTOPIA_CSV_ID_1995)_
                    NS             0             0             =         < eps
     7 c_e_SpecifiedDemand(UTOPIA_CSV_ID_1996)_
                    NS             0             0             =         < eps
     8 c_e_SpecifiedDemand(UTOPIA_CSV_ID_1997)_
                    NS             0             0             =         < eps
     9 c_e_SpecifiedDemand(UTOPIA_CSV_ID_1998)_
                    NS             0             0             =         < eps
    10 c_e_SpecifiedDemand(UTOPIA_CSV_ID_1999)_
                    NS             0             0             =         < eps
    11 c_e_SpecifiedDemand(UTOPIA_CSV_ID_2000)_
                    NS             0             0             =         < eps
    12 c_e_SpecifiedDemand(UTOPIA_CSV_ID_2001)_
                    NS             0             0             =         < eps
    13 c_e_SpecifiedDemand(UTOPIA_CSV_ID_2002)_
                    NS             0             0             =         < eps
    14 c_e_SpecifiedDemand(UTOPIA_CSV_ID_2003)_
                    NS             0             0             =         < eps
    15 c_e_SpecifiedDemand(UTOPIA_CSV_ID_2004)_
                    NS             0             0             =         < eps
```

I would be very grateful of any suggestions for either:

- How I can get each record in the output text file onto a single row, or
- Ideas on how to clean / post-process the existing text file output.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here, but the output is in a very unhelpful format at the moment!

Thanks!

Comment: Would you be willing to move into a different modeling environment? Python, for instance, has many packages which allow you to run GLPK in the backend, but which provide a programatic way of specifying input and parsing output.

Comment: Richard - thanks for your suggestion. Absolutely willing to do that if you think it's the best solution. I've done bits of Python, but am certainly no expert. If you are able to point me in the right direction / tell me what I need to read that would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a simple linear program you could post or link to? I could convert that and, presumably, from that you could figure out how to do the rest.

Comment: The LP I created is pretty huge I'm afraid - 70 MB. The link is https://kuungana-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/stephen_nash_kuungana-advisory_com/EWSWrbipBTpKs6xrt5lRPB0BkEkfAcSGpgrmjLIcNS8-Kw?e=1TcKLK (this will expire end of 12th Feb). This was actually generated using Pyomo. Do feel free to point me towards a simpler example that I can then apply to my mammoth file! Thanks.

Comment: I was hoping you would have a mathematical formulation containing some of the features of the problem you want to solve.

Comment: This file contains the objective function and details of all of the constraints in the LP?

Comment: Just choose shorter rownames. And file a notice to the GLPK help list and ask Andrew (the developer of GLPK) to use the length of the longest row name for formatting the list output.

Comment: Use -w option to get a parsable output file.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Python parser for the GLPK output file. It is not beautiful and not save (try-catch) but it is working (for pure simplex problems).

You can call it on output file:

```
outp = GLPKOutput('myoutputfile')
print(outp)
val1 = outp.getCol('mycolvar','Activity')
val2 = outp.getRow('myrowname','Upper_bound') # row names should be defined
```

The class is as follows:

```
class GLPKOutput:

    def __init__(self,filename):
        
        self.rows    = {}
        self.columns = {}

        self.nRows     = 0
        self.nCols     = 0
        self.nNonZeros = 0
        self.Status    = ""
        self.Objective = ""
        
        self.rowHeaders = []
        self.rowIdx     = {}
        self.rowWidth   = []
        self.Rows       = []
        self.hRows      = {}
        self.colHeaders = []
        self.colIdx     = {}
        self.colWidth   = []
        self.Cols       = []
        self.hCols      = {}
        
        self.wcols = ['Activity','Lower_bound','Upper bound','Marginal']
        
        self.readFile(filename)
                
    # split columns with weird line break
    def smartSplit(self,line,type,job):
    
        ret = []
        
        line = line.rstrip()
           
        if type == 'ROWS': 
            cols = len(self.rowHeaders)
            idx  = self.rowWidth
        else:              
            cols = len(self.colHeaders)
            idx  = self.colWidth
        
        if job == 'full':
            start = 0
            for i in range(cols):
                stop   = start+idx[i]+1
                ret.append(line[start:stop].strip())
                start  = stop
                
        elif job == 'part1':
            entries = line.split()
            ret     = entries[0:2]
        
        elif job == 'part2':        
            start = 0
            for i in range(cols):
                stop   = start+idx[i]+1
                ret.append(line[start:stop].strip())
                start  = stop
            ret = ret[2:]
        
        # print()
        # print("SMART:",job,line.strip())
        # print("   TO:",ret)
        return ret
        
    def readFile(self,filename):
        fp = open(filename,"r")
        lines = fp.readlines()
        fp.close
        
        i   = 0
        pos = "HEAD"

        while pos == 'HEAD' and i<len(lines):
            entries = lines[i].split()
            
            if len(entries)>0:            
                if   entries[0] == 'Rows:':
                    self.nRows = int(entries[1])
                elif entries[0] == 'Columns:':
                    self.nCols = int(entries[1])
                elif entries[0] == 'Non-zeros:':
                    self.nNonZeros = int(entries[1])
                elif entries[0] == 'Status:':
                    self.Status = entries[1]
                elif entries[0] == 'Objective:':
                    self.Objective = float(entries[3]) #' '.join(entries[1:])
                elif re.search('Row name',lines[i]):
                    lines[i] = lines[i].replace('Row name','Row_name')
                    lines[i] = lines[i].replace('Lower bound','Lower_bound')
                    lines[i] = lines[i].replace('Upper bound','Upper_bound')
                    entries  = lines[i].split()
                    pos = 'ROWS'
                    self.rowHeaders = entries
                else:
                    pass 
            
            i+= 1
            
        # formatting of row width
        self.rowWidth = lines[i].split()
        for k in range(len(self.rowWidth)): self.rowWidth[k] = len(self.rowWidth[k])
        # print("Row Widths:",self.rowWidth)
        i+= 1
        
        READY = False
        FOUND = False
        while pos == 'ROWS' and i<len(lines):
            
            if  re.match('^\s*[0-9]+',lines[i]): # new line
                if len(lines[i].split())>2: # no linebrak
                    entries = self.smartSplit(lines[i],pos,'full')
                    READY   = True
                else: # line break
                    entries = self.smartSplit(lines[i],pos,'part1')
                    READY   = False
                    FOUND   = True
            else:
                if FOUND and not READY: # second part of line
                    entries += self.smartSplit(lines[i],pos,'part2')
                    READY    = True
                    FOUND    = False
            
            if READY:                        
            
                READY = False
                FOUND = False
                
                # print("ROW:",entries)
                                
                if   re.match('[0-9]+',entries[0]): # valid line with solution data
                    self.Rows.append(entries)   
                    self.hRows[entries[1]] = len(self.Rows)-1                          
                else:
                    print("wrong line format ...")
                    print(entries)
                    sys.exit()                   
                    
            elif re.search('Column name',lines[i]):
                lines[i] = lines[i].replace('Column name','Column_name')
                lines[i] = lines[i].replace('Lower bound','Lower_bound')
                lines[i] = lines[i].replace('Upper bound','Upper_bound')
                entries  = lines[i].split()
                pos = 'COLS'
                self.colHeaders = entries
            else:                    
                pass #print("NOTHING: ",lines[i])
                    
            i+= 1

        # formatting of row width
        self.colWidth = lines[i].split()
        for k in range(len(self.colWidth)): self.colWidth[k] = len(self.colWidth[k])
        # print("Col Widths:",self.colWidth)
        i+= 1

        READY = False
        FOUND = False        
        while pos == 'COLS' and i<len(lines):
            
            if  re.match('^\s*[0-9]+',lines[i]): # new line
                if len(lines[i].split())>2: # no linebreak
                    entries = self.smartSplit(lines[i],pos,'full')
                    READY   = True
                else: # linebreak
                    entries = self.smartSplit(lines[i],pos,'part1')
                    READY   = False
                    FOUND   = True
            else:
                if FOUND and not READY: # second part of line
                    entries += self.smartSplit(lines[i],pos,'part2')
                    READY    = True
                    FOUND    = False

            if READY:        
                
                READY = False
                FOUND = False
                
                # print("COL:",entries)            
                
                if   re.match('[0-9]+',entries[0]): # valid line with solution data
                    self.Cols.append(entries)                            
                    self.hCols[entries[1]] = len(self.Cols)-1    
                else:
                    print("wrong line format ...")
                    print(entries)
                    sys.exit()

            elif re.search('Karush-Kuhn-Tucker',lines[i]):
                pos = 'TAIL'                  
            else:
                pass #print("NOTHING: ",lines[i])                    
                
            i+= 1

        for i,e in enumerate(self.rowHeaders): self.rowIdx[e] = i
        for i,e in enumerate(self.colHeaders): self.colIdx[e] = i
        
    def getRow(self,name,attr):
        if name in self.hRows:
            if attr in self.rowIdx:
                try:                
                    val = float(self.Rows[self.hRows[name]][self.rowIdx[attr]])
                except:
                    val = self.Rows[self.hRows[name]][self.rowIdx[attr]]
                return val
        else:
            return -1

    def getCol(self,name,attr):
        if name in self.hCols: 
            if attr in self.colIdx:
                try:
                    val = float(self.Cols[self.hCols[name]][self.colIdx[attr]])
                except:
                    val = self.Cols[self.hCols[name]][self.colIdx[attr]]
                return val
        else:
            print("key error:",name,"not known ...")
            return -1

        
    def __str__(self):

        retString  = '\n'+"="*80+'\nSOLUTION\n'
        retString += "nRows:      "+str(self.nRows)+'/'+str(len(self.Rows))+'\n'
        retString += "nCols:      "+str(self.nCols)+'/'+str(len(self.Cols))+'\n'
        retString += "nNonZeros:  "+str(self.nNonZeros)+'\n'
        retString += "Status:     "+str(self.Status)+'\n'
        retString += "Objective:  "+str(self.Objective)+'\n\n'
                
        retString += ' '.join(self.rowHeaders)+'\n'
        for r in self.Rows: retString += ' # '.join(r)+' #\n'
        
        retString += '\n'
        retString += ' '.join(self.colHeaders)+'\n'
        for c in self.Cols: retString += ' # '.join(r)+' #\n'
        
        return retString
```